# Geofencing api not working in android with pending intent

Tags: android, geolocation, android-location, geofencing, android-geofence

I'm trying to implement simple geofence app but its not getting triggered at all.

here is the code of what I've done so far -

```
class GeoFencingHelper(context: Context, private val task: Task, private val pendingIntent: PendingIntent){

private val geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(context)

init {
    Timber.e(task.id.toString())
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun initiateGeoFencing() {

    val geoReq  = createGeoFenceList()

    geofencingClient.addGeofences(geoReq, pendingIntent).apply {
        addOnSuccessListener {
            Timber.e("added geofence!")
        }

        addOnFailureListener {
            Timber.e("geofence failed!")
        }
    }

}

private fun createGeoFenceList(): GeofencingRequest {

    val geofenceList = arrayListOf<Geofence>()


    geofenceList.add(Geofence.Builder().apply {
        setRequestId(task.id.toString())

        setCircularRegion(
                task.location.latitude,
                task.location.longitude,
                task.range.toFloat()
        )

            // Set the expiration duration of the geofence. This geofence gets automatically
            // removed after this period of time.
        setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
        setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            // Create the geofence.

    }.build())


    
    return getGeofencingRequest(geofenceList)
}

private fun getGeofencingRequest(
    fenceList: List<Geofence>,
): GeofencingRequest {
    return GeofencingRequest.Builder().apply {
        setInitialTrigger(
            if(task.reminderCondition == ReminderCondition.ON_ENTRY)
                GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER
            else
                GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT)
        addGeofences(fenceList)
    }.build()}
```

I'm adding geofencing here

```
fun createGeoFence(context: Context, task: Task){
val geofencePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
    task.range = 150.0
    val intent = Intent(context, ReminderNotificationBroadcastReceiver::class.java)

    intent.putExtra(TASK_ID, task.id)

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 30){
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    }else{
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
}
val geoFencingHelper = GeoFencingHelper(context, task, geofencePendingIntent)

geoFencingHelper.initiateGeoFencing()}
```

here is the broadcast receiver to show notification to user when geofence event gets triggered.

```
class ReminderNotificationBroadcastReceiver @Inject constructor(private val dao: TaskDao): BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "2222")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
        .setContentTitle("Reminder \"\".")
        .setContentText("Reminder \".")
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setColor(Color.BLUE)

    with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
        notify(2222, builder.build())
    }}}
```

things I've done so far -

1. disabled battery optimization.
2. background location permission is allowed all the time.

Issue -

I used mock location apps like lockito and gps emulator to test the app.
but the geofence event is not getting triggered, I also tried to build and test sample project provided by android codelab, but I'm facing same issue in that app as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are similar questions on SO and on the net but in short, Google codelab is not up to date for this. The `PendingIntent` used for Geofencing needs to be mutable for it to work. So in your case:

```
fun createGeoFence(context: Context, task: Task){
val geofencePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
    ....

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 30){
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
    } else{
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
}
```

or just like this without the `if` as PendingIntent is mutable by default up until `Build.VERSION_CODES.R`:

```
fun createGeoFence(context: Context, task: Task){
val geofencePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
    ....

    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
}
```